# Exception thrown in constructor called by `unordered_map.emplace` crashes the program with no message

Tags: c++, exception, containers

I'm using `unordered_map<std::string, Thing>.emplace` where `Thing` is a class I wrote. `Thing` may throw an exception in its constructor.

I observed that if `Thing` throws while being constructed by `emplace`, the program simply crashes - but without any exception message. (I had to step in the debugger to figure out it was `Thing::Thing()` throwing an exception, as opposed to any other reason for a crash).

On [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace) it says

> If an exception is thrown by any operation, this function has no effect.

However - what exactly is meant by "no effect"? I figure the container would stay un-touched. But does the standard make any guarantee as to what else happens to the program? Why doesn't it show the exception as we would expect? `emplace` is not marked as `noexcept`.

EDIT:

Elaborating a little bit.

I do not attempt to `catch` this exception anywhere (if I do, it gets caught). The thing is, I am used to uncaught exceptions printing a message to the console, before crashing the app (I'm running Windows 7 with Mingw-w64 G++).

For example, here is what I'm used to get from an uncaught exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Failed to make sandwich, tomato was not good

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

However - in this case, I only get the general crash message (which I also get for segfaults, for example):

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

So the question becomes - does the standard (or at least the Mingw-w64 implementation) guarantee any sort of console output from an uncaught exception? What are the rules about when we do and when we don't receive such an output? Is the fact the I don't get an output now related to my own program, to `unorderd_map.emplace` or to something else?

Comment: *no effect* means the container is not changed.  If you post a [mre] we should be able to help you with why it just crashes instead of the exception being caught.

Comment: [\[unord.req.except\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.req.except#2): _"For unordered associative containers, if an exception is thrown by any operation other than the container's hash function from within an `insert` or `emplace` function inserting a single element, the insertion has no effect."_ - this is the only promise made, that the respective `insert` or `emplace` function has no effect [on the container]. It cannot make any promise as to what side effect _not inserting or emplacing_ an element as well as _propagating an exception (say from a ctor)_ has on the program.

Comment: Do you have an exception handler in place to catch the exception that `Thing` throws?  I tried it both [with](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zgZL4vfZFMwGJNo6) and [without](https://wandbox.org/permlink/i8MRiHptq8c8VFzd) in Wandbox and got the expected behaviour.

Comment: @PaulSanders No I don't. I am used to the fact that when an exception is thrown and not caught , the program crashes with a message such as the following: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'    what():  Failed making a sandwich                       `. And after that: `This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.`. In this case, I don't get the first part - only the second. I.e., like crashing with a segfault.

Comment: MSVC?  I didn't test with that.

Comment: @PaulSanders Compiled with Mingw-w64 G++, but running on Windows 7. So yes, I think.

Comment: @PaulSanders Is it not guaranteed by the standard that an uncaught exception displays a message before terminating?

Comment: No, they're distinct things.  And I didn't test with that either, I don't have it, but if it's a GUI app then I think that console output goes into the bit bucket.  It certainly does with MSVC.

Comment: @PaulSanders It's a console app. And elsewhere in the app if an uncaught exception happens, I get a descriptive output as I described. Seems odd. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `unordered_map` catches the exception, cleans up, and then rethrows it.  Maybe that explains why you don't get a message (even though you should).

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that after you catch the exception, the unordered_map is in the same state as it was before you attempted to insert (strong exception safety guarantee).

You say that emplace is not marked as noexcept - that is because it is allowed to throw (including in the constructor to your type). If it were marked with noexcept you would not be able to catch the exception and continue, it would call std::terminate.